# How to retrieve data from firebase using firesharp c# library (unknown exact child path)?

Tags: c#, firebase, data-retrieval, fire-sharp

I'm trying to make a database that stores dental records. I'm using firesharp library. I made a form called Register UI that registers details of new patients. Then another form called DatabaseUI where records could be retrieved from the database. Here is what my firebase structure looks like:
[Firebase Parent/child structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RELyp.png) (General Records>Patient Name>PatientDetails)

I used this code to connect to firebase:

```js
{
  IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig {
    AuthSecret = "\\mysecretcode",
      BasePath = "\\firebase url"
  };
  IFirebaseClient client;
  client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
```

The Register Form code looks like this ("Data" is a class):

```js
public async void subbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //For Gender Radio Buttons
  string gender = "";
  if (maleradio.Checked) {
    gender = "Male";
  } else {
    gender = "Female";
  }

  //Data to be stored into Firebase     
  var data = new Data {
    Name = lastnametbox.Text + ", " + firstnametbox.Text + " " + mitbox.Text,
      Age = agetbox.Text,
      Gender = gender,
      Birthdate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
  };

  if (selectdbase.Text == "General") //Store in General Records Category
  {
    SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync("General Records/" + data.Name, data);
    Data result = response.ResultAs < Data > ();
  } else //Store in Orthodontics Records Category
  {
    SetResponse resp2 = await client.SetAsync("Orthodontics Records/" + data.Name, data);
    Data result = resp2.ResultAs < Data > ();
  };


  MessageBox.Show("Registered!");
  this.Close();
}
```

Here's the code for the database form:

```js
private async void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {


  FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("General Records/" + data.Name); //'data' is unknown here
  Data obj = response.ResultAs < Data > ();


  searchtbox.Text = obj.Name;
}
```

Adding of records works fine. In retrieving from firebase, the error is at "data.Name" since that variable is in the RegistrationUI Form. The output on the textbox is always null. What path after the "General Records/" should I put since the nodes under this are varying (since they are names of patients)? Please please help.